# How to change app language by dropdown list at run time

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-translate

I am creating an android app using cordova.I want to translate all the pages between English and Arabic. `<div class="new_sub_cate_panel_single_div" id="google_translate_element" onchange="hiddenTranslateBar()"></div>`
My javascript code is  this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function googleTranslateElementInit() {

      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: '', includedLanguages: 'ar,en'}, 'google_translate_element');
      }
    function hiddenTranslateBar(){
    lang = google.translate.TranslateElement().c;

alert(lang);
 localStorage.setItem("language",lang);

            $("#:1.container").css("visibility", "hidden !important");


    }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Using this code I can change the language. But when I select another page it displays the default language. How can I convert all my app pages to another language.Is there any plugin of google translater for cordova app

Comment: When you are selecting another page again call the same method in other page. It will convert in the new page also

Comment: I tried it also ,Its not working.

Comment: did you try putting alert or something to check whether functions are getting called or not?